# WNetGetUniversalName failing when called from a scheduled task

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-server-2008-r2, delphi-xe5

I have a (win32) program that is run through a scheduled task.

When run, my software should map a number of local drive letters to UNC resources, verify that the mappings have been successful, run a few other tasks and then unmap the drives.

When running under the context of a local user, all works fine. However, when I run it through the system task scheduler, the verify task fails.

The verify tasks takes the drive letter, checks if the drive is a network drive (through `GetDriveType`) then, if the drive if of type `DRIVE_REMOTE`, calls `WNetGetUniversalName` and compare the result with the expected mapping.

When run from a regular user context, this works. But when the process is called through the task scheduler, WNetGetUniversalName fails with error 87: `The parameter is incorrect.`

After trying to isolate the issue, I came to the following conclusions:

- The issue is not linked to user rights: even when the user is made a member of both the local administrators group and the domain administrators group, the error remains.
- The parameters I pass to the functions are ALWAYS the same: It's the drive letter concatenated with `:\`.
- I have tried repeating the call after a short wait (100ms): same symptoms.
- The mapping (made through `WNetAddConnection2`) actually succeeds.
- The issue is not dependent on where the executable is located: same thing happen if it's on the local machine or run from an UNC path.
- The issue occurs whether the scheduled task has been set to "run with highest privilege" or not.

Here is the exact call I use:

```
APIResult := WNetGetUniversalName(PWideChar(pathToCheck), UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, @RemoteNameInfo, Size);
```

I'm out of ideas about what to check next.

**Edit** Right now, I have reverted to a different behavior: All drives status is checked (GetDriveType), if it's a network drive, it's unmaped, checked again and then mapped. This seems to work but it's slower (of course) and it feels less secure.

Comment: That is a normal mishap, drive letter mappings are a per-user setting.  You are likely to run the scheduled task with the wrong user account.  Otherwise the reason it works when you use a local account.  Do what works.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. unfortunately, I don't think you have understood what my tool does (or I didn't understand you comment). I'll try to add more detail about what if being done this afternoon, if that helps.